# What is the difference between sh and ./ when invoking a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line

I see people running shell scripts by typing `./scriptname`. Now this seems to be the default way, since I have seen it so often, however occasionally, but not rare, I see them type `sh scriptname`. Is it just a matter of preference or is there a more significant difference between **./** and **sh** ?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between running “bash script.sh” and “./script.sh”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136547/what-is-the-difference-between-running-bash-script-sh-and-script-sh)

Comment: Also: [What is the function of bash shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/354509/170373) and [Does the shebang determine the shell which runs the script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87560/170373)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few differences.

```
./scriptname
```

requires that the file called `scriptname` be executable, and it uses the shell specified as its first line (in the “shebang”, *e.g.* `#!/bin/sh`), if any.

```
sh scriptname
```

works as long as the file called `scriptname` is readable, and it uses `sh` (whatever that is) regardless of what the script’s shebang specifies. With some shells, if `scriptname` doesn’t exist in the current directory, the directories specified in `PATH` will be searched, and the first `scriptname` found there (if any) will be read and interpreted instead.

Put another way,

```
sh scriptname
```

will work without setup, but you might use the wrong shell, and you might run the wrong script.

```
./scriptname
```

will try to run the correct script using the right shell (or at least, the shell specified by the script’s author, if any), but it might need some setup first (`chmod a+x scriptname`).