# Replace strings in shell. Error: Bad substitution

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to replace all white spaces with _.
I used the following code:

```
FONT="DejaVu Sans Mono"
FONT_CODE=${FONT//[ ]/_}
echo $FONT_CODE
```

I'm expecting DejaVu_Sans_Mono as the output
But I got the following error :

```
x.sh: 2: Bad substitution
```

I am not sure what I need to do to get work.

Comment: You tagged this `shell` - which shell are you using, specifically? POSIX `sh` doesn't support that syntax for example

Comment: @steeldriver I am using Linux mint.. I used the command sh x.sh

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I used zsh and it worked for me

Comment: A better soultion would be to add an appropriate "shebang", make the script executable, and then just call it by name, `./x.sh`. See for example [What is the function of bash shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354509/what-is-the-function-of-bash-shebang)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved my issue after getting hints from the comments.
I used zsh instead of sh and it worked for me.

First, I had to install zsh:

```
sudo apt install zsh
```

Then, I used zsh instead of sh in the terminal:

```
zsh x.sh
```

I got no error and this is the output:

> DejaVu_Sans_Mono

Comment: To make it work in `sh`, just do `printf '%s' "$FONT" | tr ' ' '_'`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Well, that's in case if you want to print immediately. What about if you want to assign it to a variable?

Comment: Use an ordinary command substitution: `variable=$( printf '%s' "$FONT" | tr ' ' '_' )`  I'm also noting that the code in your question ends with outputting the modified value, so it shouldn't be necessary to store it in an intermediate variable.